# why tun interface in openvpn

Tags: vpn, openvpn, tap, tun

can anyone tell me the use of tun interface in openvpn?
as far as i read, it is used to tunnel all the traffic from the PC over the ssl tunnel.
But incase of VPN, i suppose all the traffic initiated from remote-pc should have the ip-address assigned from the private network by the ssl-vpn server.
So does tun interface helps in identifyin the source-ip to be used for all traffic from remote pc?
Or is there any doc explains how the openvpn client side works for better understanding?

Thanks,
summa.

Answer (score 3):

tun or tap devices are the network adapters of the openvpn tunnel, like eth0 is for the LAN or tap adapter for a modem connection. They are assigned an IP by the vpn server.

[principle behind openvpn tunnels](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/faq/75-general/293-what-is-the-principle-behind-openvpn-tunnels.html)